# this seems to be underlined in red

Tags: java, swing, changelistener

Revised

Now the import appears underlined here

import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

and also the line below appears underlined

slider.addChangeListener(ChangeListener());

I am not clear on this at all

Full Code

```
package areaofrectangleslider;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;


public class Areaofrectangleslider extends JFrame implements 
        ActionListener, ChangeListener {

    private JPanel panel;
    private Random random;
    private javax.swing.Timer timer;
    private JSlider slider;
    private JTextField gapField;
    private JLabel gapLabel;



    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run(){
        Areaofrectangleslider frame = new Areaofrectangleslider();
        frame.setSize(250,300);
        frame.createGUI();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        }


    });
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     //   throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    int x, y, size;
    Graphics paper = panel.getGraphics();
    x = random.nextInt(200);
    y = random.nextInt(200);
    size = random.nextInt(20);
    paper.fillOval(x, y, size, size);

    }

    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue observable, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {
       // throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    int timeGap = slider.getValue();
    gapField.setText(Integer.toString(timeGap));
    timer.setDelay(timeGap);

    }

    private void createGUI() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Container window = getContentPane();
        window.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        random = new Random();

        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,200));
        panel.setBackground(Color.white);
        window.add(panel);

        gapLabel = new JLabel("TIme Gap: ");
        window.add(gapLabel);
        gapField = new JTextField(10);
        window.add(gapField);

        slider = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL,200,2000,1000);
        window.add(slider);
        slider.addChangeListener(ChangeListener());
        gapField.setText(Integer.toString(slider.getValue()));
        timer = new javax.swing.Timer(1000, this);
        timer.start();



//        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

}
```

Old

I cant seem to work out why i get the error here

```
slider.addChangeListener(this);
```

(`this`) appears underlined in red

The console readout i get is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: areaofrectangleslider.Areaofrectangleslider cannot be cast to javax.swing.event.ChangeListener
    at areaofrectangleslider.Areaofrectangleslider.createGUI(Areaofrectangleslider.java:91)
    at areaofrectangleslider.Areaofrectangleslider.main(Areaofrectangleslider.java:46)
Java Result:
```

Full code below

```
package areaofrectangleslider;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class Areaofrectangleslider extends JFrame implements 
        ActionListener, ChangeListener {

    private JPanel panel;
    private Random random;
    private javax.swing.Timer timer;
    private JSlider slider;
    private JTextField gapField;
    private JLabel gapLabel;



    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Areaofrectangleslider frame = new Areaofrectangleslider();
        frame.setSize(250,300);
        frame.createGUI();
        frame.setVisible(true);


    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     //   throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    int x, y, size;
    Graphics paper = panel.getGraphics();
    x = random.nextInt(200);
    y = random.nextInt(200);
    size = random.nextInt(20);
    paper.fillOval(x, y, size, size);

    }

    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue observable, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {
       // throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    int timeGap = slider.getValue();
    gapField.setText(Integer.toString(timeGap));
    timer.setDelay(timeGap);

    }

    private void createGUI() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Container window = getContentPane();
        window.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        random = new Random();

        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,200));
        panel.setBackground(Color.white);
        window.add(panel);

        gapLabel = new JLabel("TIme Gap: ");
        window.add(gapLabel);
        gapField = new JTextField(10);
        window.add(gapField);

        slider = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL,200,2000,1000);
        window.add(slider);
        slider.addChangeListener(this);
        gapField.setText(Integer.toString(slider.getValue()));
        timer = new javax.swing.Timer(1000, this);
        timer.start();



//        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

}
```

Comment: DO NOT EVER USE `getGraphics()`, this is not how custom painting works.  See [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details

Comment: Good description of your problem and full code example.  More folks should ask questions like this.

Answer (score 5):

`javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;` is not the same as `javax.swing.event.ChangeListener`

NEVER use `getGraphics` to try and perform custom painting, this is not how painting works in Swing.  See [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details about how custom painting works and should be implemented in Swing

Also (as commented below), all UI creations and modifications should be carried out within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Areaofrectangleslider frame = new Areaofrectangleslider();
            frame.setSize(250,300);
            frame.createGUI();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

See [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) for more details

Comment: Also, all Swing code should be done on the [Event Dispatch Thread.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)  The `main()` entry point does not, at minimum.

Comment: @markspace Or at least you should never assume that `main` will be called within the context of the EDT

Answer (score 0):

Method signature of the addChangeListner in JSlider is 
   `public void addChangeListener(ChangeListener l)`
where ChangeListner is `javax.swing.event.ChangeListener`. So in your code you are passing `javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener` type which is wrong and it cannot be casted into.

Comment: I dont understand, javax.swing.event.ChangeListener is not an import available

Comment: @MrAssistance [Yes it is](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/ChangeListener.html)

Comment: I have posted my new code above - i am pretty stuck with this